# VBA - Based on User Input - look up value in table

Tags: vba, matrix, user-input, lookup, userform

I have created a form that asks for two user inputs, site location and sku. Site location is a drop down and SKU is a text box. Below it there is a textbox which I want to populate based on user input after they hit the "whats my price?" button.[user form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/413kH.png)

I have a matrix of prices with the SKU in column B and the sites across the top in row 1 with their respective prices in the matrix(columns D-H).  I have attached a sample of the table. Please note that the "SKU" and "Site" titles will not be in my actual matrix.

[pricing table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8q6fD.png)

I need assistance coding the "What's my price?" button in the user form.

I feel as though I would need an if statement using some sort of look up but i'm a little lost as to how to start the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you have to do:

- Read the value from the site field;
- Read the value from the SKU    field;
- Display the matching in the Your Price is field, using the    following formula:

  WorksheetFunction.Index(Range,site field, sku field)

More about WorksheetFunction.Index here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197581.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Application.Match` on the row and the column independently, then get the corresponding cell. Try the following code, but replace the control's names (txtSku, cmbSite) and the sheet's code name (mySheet) with yours.

```
Sub WhatsMyPrice_Click()
  Dim rowNum, colNum
  rowNum = Application.Match(txtSku.Value, MySheet.Range("B:B"), 0)
  If IsError(rowNum) Then MsgBox "SKU not found": Exit Sub
  colNum = Application.Match(cmbSite.Value, MySheet.Rows(2), 0)
  If IsError(rowNum) Then MsgBox "Site not found": Exit Sub
  txtPrice.Value = MySheet.Cells(rowNum, colNum).Value2
End Sub
```

Comment: Do the rowNum and colNum need to be declared as a string? The user could input either a number, a number with a decimal, or a number with letters. I am receiving an error in the second line of your code, "rowNum=..." I have the textbox labeled as you had and MySheet changed to AllSites and the range was "A:A" on my worksheet.'

Comment: @Melissa rowNum and colNum are declared as `Variant`. Basically they are integers, but `Application.Match` may return an error code. As for the other parameters, they are read from the controls and they may be anything, numbers or strings. You might want to force the site number into an integer by using `CLng(txtSku.Value)`.

Comment: I got the error to go away for the 'row num' line by entering : rowNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(txtSKU.Value, Worksheets("AllSites").Range("A:A"), 0)
But now i am having trouble with the colNum line code. I have it currently as: colNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(cbxSite.Value, Worksheets("AllSites").Range("C:G"), 0)
Since there are 5 sites the range has to include the five columns and match the price based on which site is chosen correct? that's what the application.match does?
I've never used that function so i'm not familiar with its capabilities.