# VBA Target intersection cell depending on row and columns headers and on userform values

Tags: excel, vba, cell, intersection

My name is Arno, based in France and I am a regular user of stackoverflow where I usually find many answers.
But this time I am stuck... I am familiar with making userform that print, export in PDF and record in database, and this time I want my trainers to record training information in a database.
You will certainly say that it is simple to enter directly the date values in the excel sheet. But the userform actually has other fields to be completed and will be exported as a training certificate in PDF format (to avoid more and more paper). This is why I am using a userform.

[Overall scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvdR9.jpg)

I have a command button "record training" that triggers the purple userform just below. I want some of the data of this usf to be recorded in the database you see on the left. They are combo boxes with defined lists (except for the date).

First, I need to target for example the cell at the intersection of "Peter" and code "B". As far as I understand i need to find a match between the value of my "NAME" field of my usf and the line where all names are listed. Same for the code (match between the "CODE "field value and the column

Then I need to determine the intersection of this row and column, and this is where I want the "DATE" field value of the usf to be written.

And finally, depending on the value of the "MARK" field that can be "Good" or "to be reviewed" or "not good", the color of the cell containing the date would have 3 possible different colors. The final result would be the second table with dates and colors, all nice and pretty.

I do not know how to find the intersection cell for my table and put the date in it and I am not sure how to fix the color stuff of the final targeted cell.

I also have no code to propose, but the sheet could be "sheet1" and combo boxes could be named cbDate, cbName, cbCode etc... in your propositions.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Use `Match()` to get the row/column position, based on "Trainer" and "Code".  If you run into problems with that, edit your question to show the code you tried, and explain the specific problem you're having with it.

Comment: Hi Tim, thank youy for your suggestion. I"ll do that.

Comment: Similar Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43850243/vba-based-on-user-input-look-up-value-in-table

Comment: Hello Tim,I have used your suggestion "similar" to write some code, so here it is:

Answer (score 0):

I am back after different tests.
My table:
[My table to fill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moOmj.png)

My userform:
[My userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i47wc.png)

And now my code based on what Tim suggested me as "similar" which I find very close to what I try to achieve.

```
Private Sub cbRecord_Click()

Dim employee As Variant
employee = cbName.Value

Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = Worksheets("TrainingSheet")

Dim CodeColumn 'variant as default
Set CodeColumn = Application.Match(cbCode.Value, sht.Range("B:B"), 0)

Dim NameLine 'variant as default
Set NameLine = Application.Match(employee, sht.Range("C2:H2"), 0)

Dim thedate As String
thedate = tbDate.Value


If IsError(NameLine) Then MsgBox "Sorry, employee not found in the sheet": Exit Sub
If IsError(CodeColumn) Then MsgBox "Training Code not found in the sheet": Exit Sub

WorksheetFunction.Index(NameLine, CodeColumn).Value = thedate

End Sub
```

I have now an error on the `Set CodeColumn and NameLine` ERROR 13 TYPE INCOMPATIBILITY and I do not know where that comes from.

I have looked on english and french sites, tried `application.workfunction.Match` (no success), set my table values as text, as numeric, etc (no success), changed the variant type, etc.. always the same error.

Is it possible for you to help?
Many thanks.
Arno

Comment: It's best to edit your question https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76993750/edit if you need to add comments or code - if you post an answer the people may pass over your question assuming it has already been answered.

Comment: Please include any additional information/code/debugging details to the original question, not as an answer.

Comment: `Set CodeColumn = ...` should be `CodeColumn = ...`   Match() doesn't return an object-type value, so you can't use `Set` there.

Comment: Hello, thank you both for your inputs and corrections but I cannot see how you formatted my text in your post... Indeed it works without the "Set". I have now the message error "employee not found" on the [NameLine] as it does not seem to find a match between the employee combobox.value and a similar value in the specified range. This mistake does not occur for the [ColumnCode]. I've looked at the value types (standard, numbers, etc), my lists that populate the employee combobox, but it just doesn't work...

Comment: Hello, I finally found a complete solution which I would like to propose here as it works and may help others. Should I edit my first post and put it there or propose another "Answer". Thx.